# Cassandra Datastax Java Driver not preparing Query properly

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm using the cassandra-driver-core version 3.0.2 and Cassandra version 3.3.

Whenever I run a single slice on multiple clustering columns the driver cannot successfully prepare the statement.

So for a very simple example say I have a Cassandra table that contains a partition key and three clustering columns. The query I'm trying to run looks like this:

```
SELECT val FROM table WHERE pk = ? AND (c1, c2, c3) <= (?, ?, ?)
```

So whenever I run this query in and try to bind the parameters to the query, this particular query will hang. I've tested this query in Cassandra itself, and it seems to work. Also if I substitute in the clustering column values with still preparing the statement, so for example:

```
SELECT val FROM table WHERE pk = ? AND (c1, c2, c3) <= (1, 4, 6)
```

The query will work. This query will be used a lot so I would like to prepare it for performance reasons. I could not find anyone else encountering this problem and it's specific to running a slice query on multiple clustering columns. If I was doing a comparison against only one clustering column the query would be able to be prepared successfully.

Also I'm not receiving any errors when running this code. It is done asynchronously and it just never responds with either an error or success. So I think somewhere in the Datastax Driver it is hanging. I tried finding where in the debugger but had little success.

Comment: include Cassandra version please

Comment: When you say 'this particular query will hang' do you mean that the future returned from session.executeAsync() never completes?   The driver should mark the future as failed after SocketOptions.getReadTimeoutMillis (default 12s) if cassandra hasn't responded.   If it isn't not doing that, that sounds like a bug in that handling at least.  Can you share you code of how you are handling the future?

Comment: Just tried this out and it worked for me on 3.0.8, maybe it is something tied to the C* version as Chris suggests.

Comment: this works fine with java driver 3.0.2 and C* 3.6 for what its worth

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Cassandra 3.3. It either hangs on the session.executeAsync() and never completes or never completes the statement.bind(). statement.bind() isn't asynchronous or anything, so I don't see how that could never be completing so it probably is session.executeAsync(). The code is actually written in Scala, but I can provide it if it would help, I'm not totally convinced it's a problem in error handling though because invalid queries and other errors are caught by the error handling no problem.

Comment: Given both andy and I tried it in same(ish) version and it worked, there may be something wrong with your code/handling async. may be worth including.  Fwiw: `PreparedStatement p = s.prepare("SELECT val FROM test.test WHERE pk = ? AND (c1, c2, c3) <= (?,?,?)");
            System.out.println(s.executeAsync(p.bind(1, 2, 3, 4)).get().one());` works